# Is there a way to convert a .obj file from Lightwave 3D to .h file for OpenGL ES in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, 3d

I am looking for a way to convert a .obj file of Lightwave 3D to a .h file for iPhone. I looked around and has seen several scripts that can generate .h files for you, but all of them cannot understand Lightwave 3D .obj format. If anyone appears to know some sort of methods that can translate lightwave 3d .obj files to .h file, please share.

Or better, if anyone appears to know some other ways to make .h files, please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff Lamarche also has a number of posts on conversion of Blender files to .h files under the [OpenGL ES tag](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/search/label/OpenGL%20ES) at his blog. He's posted a [Python script](http://innerloop.biz/code/objc.py.zip) that was iteratively improved by the community (notably Scott Lyons and Dennis Ippel).

I'm not aware of a script that does the export straight from Lightwave, so it currently looks like you'll have to go through Blender first...

Comment: Jeff Lamarche's python plug in seems a bit hit and miss, I guessing because of versioning problems. He has an App which in Objective C which reads OBJ files but it really is slow.... the cesna plane litterally takes minutes to load!! It is not a viable option for a shipping iOS product. Apple recomends static data objects.

Comment: Uhum cough cough.... I've written an app in Mono C# which reads OBJ and MTL files and produces Objective C/C/C++ headers file and is really quick. Will put in live in the next week or so on github.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps convert the .obj file to a Blender file, and [export a header file from that](http://espressosoft.com/wordpress/?p=21).

Answer (score 1):

Simon Maurice's [OpenGL ES series](http://web.me.com/smaurice/AppleCoder/iPhone_OpenGL/iPhone_OpenGL.html) has a 3 part article ([I](http://web.me.com/smaurice/AppleCoder/iPhone_OpenGL/Entries/2009/6/17_OpenGL_ES_14_-_Getting_Access_to_Blender_Models__Part_1.html), [II](http://web.me.com/smaurice/AppleCoder/iPhone_OpenGL/Entries/2009/6/18_OpenGL_ES_15_-_Getting_Access_to_Blender_Models__Part_2.html) & [III](http://web.me.com/smaurice/AppleCoder/iPhone_OpenGL/Entries/2009/6/22_OpenGL_ES_16_-_Blender_Models_Part_3__Textures_and_UV_Mapped_Objects.html)) on leveraging Blender's python interface to bring models into OpenGL ES iPhone applications. It includes a step-by-step guide and sample projects.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you've asked for but I've written a [step-by-step guide](http://www.everita.com/lightwave-collada-and-opengles-on-the-iphone) on how to get a LightWave model into OpenGL ES via COLLADA.

Answer (score 0):

Cheetah 3d at www.cheetah3d.com is a mac-only 3d modeling tool that exports obj as .h